# Showing Full Hierarchy on Agile Board

Tags: jira, agile, scrum

I'm using the Epic -> Story -> Task -> Subtask scheme, and attempting to view all of my issues, but... I don't think I can. Here's an example:

> Epic: Paladin - Level 60
>
> Story (linked to Epic): Get to Level 10
>
> Task (linked to Story): Do Level 1 Quest
>
> Sub-Task (linked to Task above): Questgiver Is Nonfunctional

If I sort by epics or story, I can't see my subtask. I'd like to see the full hierarchy, not just two, or three levels of it... Is this possible, somehow? I don't feel like I or my team should have to click individually through each issue on the board to see the subtasks. I'm hoping that I'm just missing a setting in front of my face, or something.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is maybe that you're looking in the Backlog view of a Board - where Subtasks are not visible - but once you start the Sprint, then you'll see the Subtasks under the Tasks in the Active sprints view of the Board

Answer (score 0):

On JIRA Board you can see a list of Stories (Story is a synonyme to Task). There are also Sub-tasks visible, however you have to make sure that Sub-tasks are not filtered out by JIRA Board filter.

When you click on the story a new section will pop up on the right side. There will be information about Epic. So, finally you have everything in one place: Epic, Story (Task) and Sub-tasks.

What you can do you can also create Board for each Epic, so you don't need to click on Task to see Epic it belong to. Yet another way is to create Board custom fileters assigned to certain Epics. Then you can filter by pressing Epic button.